# Equation exercise involving nth-roots in Serge Lang's Basic Mathematics.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Chapter 3 section 3 *Powers and roots***.
The last excercise is solving for $x$ in the following equation:
$$(3x + 5)^{-4} = 64$$

Lang lists two answers for this equation. The first answer I can arrive pretty easily:
$$\frac{1}{(3x+5)^4} = 64$$
$$\frac{\pm 1}{3x+5} = \pm \sqrt{8}$$
$$\pm1 = \pm\sqrt{8}(3x + 5)$$
Therefore:
$$x_1: \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} = 3x + 5$$
$$x_2: \frac{-1}{\sqrt{8}} = 3x + 5$$
Furthermore:
$$x_1 = \frac{1 - 5\sqrt{8}}{3\sqrt{8}}$$
$$x_2 = \frac{-1 - 5\sqrt{8}}{3\sqrt{8}}$$

Which is the first solution that Lang provides.

But the author also gives the following solution for the same equation:
$$x = \frac{-40 \pm \sqrt{8}}{24}$$

I'm having trouble arriving to this second solution. I'm doing several manipulations but always arrive at the first answer.

If someone can give some insight or show me how to arrive to the second solution I'll be grateful.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: "Exercise", not "excercise".

Comment: To get the second solution, simply multiply top and bottom of the first solution by $\sqrt8$ to get rid of the radical in the denominator

Comment: The original equation can have at most two solutions, so either Lang is wrong or the second pair of solutions is the same as the first pair. You can check that Lang is not wrong by clearing the $\sqrt{8}$ from the denominator in the first solution. (All the arithmetic here is going on the the field $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ (because $\sqrt{8} = 2\sqrt{2}$): in that field every element can be written in the form $p + q\sqrt{2}$ for rational $p$ and $q$ and Lang is (effectively) giving that form in his second solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{-40 \pm \sqrt{8}}{24}$ is actually the same as $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Notice that you can rewrite $x_1$ as:

$$\frac{1}{3\sqrt{8}} - \frac{5}{3}$$
$$= \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{3}$$
using $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$:
$$ \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{3} =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12} - \frac{20}{12}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{8}}{24} - \frac{40}{24} = \frac{-40 + \sqrt{8}}{24}$$

You can do the same thing with $x_2$ to get $\frac{-40 - \sqrt{8}}{24}$

Comment: Thank you so much! That's why I was arriving at the same answer over and over because I didn't moved beyond that. Just a quick question, why did you multiplied by 2 the fractions with the 12 in the denominator? Was it only to match the given solution? Or it was a necessary step? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: The fractions were multiplied by the number 1, in the form 2/2.

Comment: Now I see it. Thank you, you both helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Like J.W. Tanner pointed out, multiplying by $1$ in the form $\frac{\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{8}}$ gets us:
$$x = (\frac{\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{8}}) (\frac{-5\sqrt{8} \pm 1}{3\sqrt{8}}) = \frac{-40 \pm \sqrt{8}}{24}$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$x_1 = \frac{1 - 5\sqrt{8}}{3\sqrt{8}}$$
> $$x_2 = \frac{-1 - 5\sqrt{8}}{3\sqrt{8}}$$
> is the first solution.   How to arrive to the second solution?

In order to get this radical expression in [simplified form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Simplified_form_of_a_radical_expression),

get rid of radicals in the denominator by multiplying by $\dfrac{\sqrt8}{\sqrt8}=1$ to get

$$x_1 = \frac{\sqrt8 - 5\cdot8}{3\cdot8}$$
$$x_2 = \frac{-\sqrt8 - 5\cdot{8}}{3\cdot8}.$$

Can you see how these are equal to the second solution?